# azure file share error 53 on windows clients but servers work fine

Tags: azure

First post on this forum, hoping someone can help...

We have a small network comprising Windows 10 Pro clients and Server 2012 R2 domain controller. There is also a File server and a Print server. All servers run on VMware (free 5.5 version of VSphere) .

Ive set up an azure account. Id like to move away from our on prem system to full cloud based to help upgrade our system without much up front outlay.

Starting with Storage, I've created 4 x Azure File shares. The Windows servers will all map a drive to the storage account and share but the windows 10 clients simply will not. They all report error 53. The TCP connection test succeeds on the servers but fails on the windows 10 clients. As the connection works on the servers, im sure its not an ISP 445 closed problem. The WIndows 10 clients behave the same way on both a local account and a domain account, ruling out GPO interference.

Anyone have any idea who to remedy this problem having come across it themselves?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Ray

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you taken? Have you followed the steps suggested in the documentation - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems#error-53-error-67-or-error-87-when-you-mount-or-unmount-an-azure-file-share

Comment: It can be caused by restricted NTLM on Win10 clients

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message I would suggest you try the below mentioned test connection and let me know the screen shot.

Test-NetConnection -ComputerName ([System.Uri]::new($storageAccount.Context.FileEndPoint).Host) -Port 445

Instructions here - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows

A workaround for port 445 is to setup a VPN tunnel - https://github.com/RenaShahMSFT/AzureFilesVPN

System error 53 has occurred. The network path was not found.

System error 53 or system error 67 can occur if port 445 outbound communication to an Azure Files datacenter is blocked. To see the summary of ISPs that allow or disallow access from port 445, go to TechNet.

If the issue still persists, can you share the screenshot of the error message and ISP provider name.

Hope this helps!

Do click on "Mark as Answer" and Upvote on the post that helps you, this can be beneficial to other community members.